# Any way to simplify this code, more efficient?

Tags: php, language-agnostic

Is there any way to simplify this code? the "elseif" statement does not seem to be working and is causing my application to throw out errors.

```
if(@@Employee_Position=="Manager") {

    if(@@CER_BioMed == "Y" && @@CER_PO == "Y")
        @%ISINDEX=5;
    elseif(@@CER_BioMed == "Y" && @@CER_PO != "Y")
        @%ISINDEX=4;
    elseif(@@CER_BioMed != "Y" && @@CER_PO == "Y")
        @%ISINDEX=4;
    else
        @%ISINDEX=3;
    }
else {
    if(@@CER_BioMed == "Y" && @@CER_PO == "Y")
        @%ISINDEX=6;
    elseif(@@CER_BioMed == "Y" && @@CER_PO != "Y")
        @%ISINDEX=5;
    elseif(@@CER_BioMed != "Y" && @@CER_PO == "Y")
        @%ISINDEX=5;
    else
        @%ISINDEX=4;
}
```

UPDATE: Sorry about not being clear. First time posting here. It's in php language. It's a php trigger for Processmaker BPS.

Comment: You tagged this both php and javascript... Which is it?  I'm guessing php?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: seems like a template that's gonna be filled in by either I'm guessing PHP or JavaScript. Oh, no, wait.. this is *the* code!

Comment: It's been asked, but I can't help it; *seriously, what language **is** this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on what's given, I'd go with something like this:

```
if(@@CER_BioMed == "Y" && @@CER_PO == "Y")
    @%ISINDEX=5;
elseif(@@CER_BioMed != "Y" XOR @@CER_PO != "Y")
    @%ISINDEX=4;
else
    @%ISINDEX=3;

if(@@Employee_Position=="Manager")
    @%ISINDEX-=1;
```

Assuming whatever language this is supports the `-=` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Since I don't know what language that is, I'll keep it somewhat language agnostic:

```
isindex = 3;
if (employee_position != 'manager') {
    isindex++;
}
if (cer_biomed == 'y') {
    isindex++;
}
if (cer_po == 'y') {
    isindex++;
}
```

Comment: This feels a bit fragile and prone to breaking when the code is re-visited later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language this is, but:

```
elseif(@@CER_BioMed == "Y" && @@CER_PO != "Y")
              @%ISINDEX=4;    // or 5
           elseif(@@CER_BioMed != "Y" && @@CER_PO == "Y")
              @%ISINDEX=4;    // or 5
```

seems to be a clear case of `OR`:

```
elseif(@@CER_BioMed == "Y" || @@CER_PO == "Y")
              @%ISINDEX=4;    // or 5
```

Comment: While in the context of the first `if` statement, it doesn't matter, this would actually be a case of `XOR`, not `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

Compute a number between 0 and 7 using

```
lookup_table_index = (
    ((@@Employee_Position=="Manager") << 2)
     | ((@@CER_BioMed == "Y") << 1)
     | (@@CER_PO == "Y"))
```

and then use that as an index into an array of length 8 with values for @%INDEX.

```
lookup_table = [4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

and then you can compute your index

```
 INDEX = lookup_table[lookup_table_index]
```